# Android ListView locks its current screen and doesnt scroll when phone is rotated only the item before rotation is visible

Tags: android, android-activity, android-listview, rotation, android-adapter

Hi guys I am having a real annoying problem that steals my time which could be very simple but ,I need your help .I tried almost all the approaches but none of them worked.

```
<activity
android:name="activities.UserMainActivity"
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
android:label="@string/title_activity_user_main" >
```

and tried both writing **configChanges**  and not writing even changed my custom class to **parcellable** but no result.And No Exception is thrown.

And when I debug and watch the the custom adapter it is filled with all items near 30 records .Any help will be APPRECIATED

Answer (score 0):

Ohhhh my god , it is an extremely simple detail . I just edited my **activity's layout** . I was having my **ListView** in **Relative Layout** and this **Relative Layout** was in a **ScrollView** , Removing this ScrollView Solved my Day-Consuming Problem.However if I remove `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` part ListView works well but on rotation scrolls back to top (a **Tip**).

```
 <--<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 android:id="@+id/scrollView1" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:fillViewport="true" >-->

<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listQuestion"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>

<!-- </ScrollView> -->
```